# Is it secure to use web3 library into client fronted application?

Tags: blockchain, web3js, quorum

I have reading about Quorum Blockchain and I have try some code into my laptop.

I'm using the web3 library to executing some tests with a sample Quorum net. I have seen that this library allows you to deploy smart contracts and make transactions so I have the following question:

Is it secure to use web3 library into client fronted application or it's thinking to use only on the server side with node?

Comment: it's completely safe mate as you basically invoke to read/add.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe.

Unless you connect to a node with an insecure setting. For example, if the accounts on the node are unlocked, then someone could use the web3 object in your frontend to send transactions by using these accounts.